# Eliminating IP addresses from a log file through the console

Tags: regex, bash, sed, scripting, data-manipulation

I'm trying to eliminate from a log file some lines containing IP addresses. I'm currently using a bash script using the sed command. I'm running it on Ubuntu 16.04.
The log file has this format

```
...        //data type 1
...        //data type 2
0.0.0.0    //IP 1
...
...
127.0.0.1  //IP 2
```

and so on.
The command i'm running is

```
sed 's/\b[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\b//g' input.txt > output.txt
```

also

```
sed '/\b[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\b/d' input.txt > output.txt
```

and some other variants.

But nothing happens

The problem is that in regex tester website like regextester.com the expression does actually evidentiate the IP address i want to eliminate.

Please can someone give me a hint?

Comment: Leading word boundary is `\<` and trailing is `\>`, replace the two `\b`s accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that here nothing happens:

```
$ sed 's/\b[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\b//g' input.txt
...        //data type 1
...        //data type 2
0.0.0.0    //IP 1
...
...
127.0.0.1  //IP 2
```

Here, however, `sed` successfully removes the IPs:

```
$ sed -E 's/\b[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\b//g' input.txt
...        //data type 1
...        //data type 2
    //IP 1
...
...
  //IP 2
```

`-E` turns on extended regular expressions.

Alternatively, one can succeed with sed with basic regular expression (that is, without `-E`) if  the `{` are escaped:

```
$ sed  's/\b[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\b//g' input.txt
...        //data type 1
...        //data type 2
    //IP 1
...
...
  //IP 2
```

`\b` feature is a GNU extension.  It may be absent in other versions of sed.

#### Simplification

The regex above involves a lot of repetition.  That can be reduced as follows:

```
$ sed -E 's/[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}//g' input.txt
...        //data type 1
...        //data type 2
    //IP 1
...
...
  //IP 2
```

#### Compatibility Note

For old versions of GNU sed, you may may need to use `-r` in place of `-E`.

`\b` for boundary is supported by GNU sed and may be absent in others.

Comment: Found the solution by myself but it was just that!

I used

    sed -r '.....'

Thanks for your reply though!